# Prism - moving data between viewmodels

Tags: prism

I'm struggling to find the best implementation.

I'm using Prism and I have a View (ParentView), which has a small region within it. Depending on the item in a ddl, another smaller view (ChildView) gets injected into the region of the ParentView.

The ChildView will just have some properties which I would like to access from the ParentView.

So I realize I can use a Publish/Subscribe method to move data between viewmodels, but the issue is I have nothing to hang the Publish on. The view is made up of TextBoxes and no event triggers. The ChildView can be vastly different based on the selection of the ddl. I like the clean separation of each ChildView being it's own view injected inside the ParentView.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to implement the interface INavigationAware in your viewmodels. After that you can use the methods onNavigatedFrom(), onNavigatedTo() and onNavigatingTo() to register your event.

**EDIT:**

If you want launch the event when a field in the child is changed you can do something like this:

```
private string _yourField;

public string YourField
        {
            get { return _yourField; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _yourField, value); 
                  //Here you can launch the event
                }
        }
```

In this case when YourField change the event is launched.

Comment: I did think about that. But the Navigation methods are only hit when the ChildView gets loaded. I needed to get the property values of ChildView after they've been filled in.

Comment: I edited my response. Check if this can be a good solution for you.

Comment: Thanks! You were close. I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few implementations, but the one that worked was creating a singleton instance of the ChildView (childviewmodel) and then gaining access to the properties through the instance. It may not be pretty, but it works.

```
    private static ChildViewModel _instance = new ChildViewModel ();
    public static ChildViewModel Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    #region Properties

    private ChildModel _childModel= new ChildModel ();
    public ChildModel _childModel
    {
        get { return _instance._childModel; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _instance._childModel, value);
        }
    }

    private string _childProperty1;
    public string ChildProperty1
    {
        get { return _childProperty1; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _childProperty1, value);
            ChildModel.ChildProperty1= _childProperty1;
        }
    }
```

In reality - there were many childproperties. I only listed one for demo. And then I call it in ParentView

```
 var _instance = ChildViewModel.Instance;
 var _cm = _instance.ChildModel;

 _parentModel = new ParentModel
 {
     Property1= ParentViewProperty1,
     Property2= _cm.ChildProperty1,
  };
```

Hope that helps someone else.